# Complex changes to a URL with sed

Tags: regex, url, sed

I am trying to parse an RSS feed on the Linux command line which involves formatting the raw output from the feed with sed.

I currently use this command:

```
feedstail -u http://www.heise.de/newsticker/heise-atom.xml -r -i 60 -f "{published}> {title} {link}" | sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{13\}\)\(.\{6\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3\5/'
```

This gives me a number of feed items per line that look like this:

```
Sat 20:33 GMT> WhatsApp-Ausfall: Server-Probleme blockieren Messaging-Dienst http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/WhatsApp-Ausfall-Server-Probleme-blockieren-Messaging-Dienst-2121664.html/from/atom10?wt_mc=rss.ho.beitrag.atom
```

Notice the long URL at the end. I want to shorten this to better fit on the command line. Therefore, I want to change my sed command to produce the following:

```
Sat 20:33 GMT> WhatsApp-Ausfall: Server-Probleme blockieren Messaging-Dienst http://www.heise.de/-2121664
```

That means cutting everything out of the URL except a dash and that seven digit number preceeding the ".html/blablabla" bit.

Currently my sed command only changes stuff in the date bit. It would have to leave the title and start or the URL alone and then cut stuff out of it until it reaches the seven digit number. It needs to preserve that and then cut everything after it out. Oh yeah, and we need to leave a dash right in front of that number too.

I have no idea how to do that and can't find the answer after hours of googling. Help?

**EDIT:**

This is the raw output of a line of `feedstail -u http://www.heise.de/newsticker/heise-atom.xml -r -i 60 -f "{published}> {title} {link}"`, in case it helps:

```
Sat, 22 Feb 2014 20:33:00 GMT> WhatsApp-Ausfall: Server-Probleme blockieren Messaging-Dienst http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/WhatsApp-Ausfall-Server-Probleme-blockieren-Messaging-Dienst-2121664.html/from/atom10?wt_mc=rss.ho.beitrag.atom
```

**EDIT 2:**

It seems I can only pipe that output into one command. Piping it through multiple ones seems to break things. I don't understand why ATM.

Comment: Can you please post the output of your command without piping it to `sed`? Are you open to `awk` solutions?

Comment: Just put that into an edit. And yes, awk would work too. As long as I can pipe my output into a single command, I'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately (for me), I could only think of solving this with *extended* regexp syntax (either -E or -r flag on different systems):

```
... | sed -E 's|(://[^/]+/).*(-[0-9]+)\.html/.*|\1\2|'
```

**UPDATE:** In basic regexp syntax, the best I can do is

```
... | sed 's|\(://[^/]*/\).*\(-[0-9][0-9]*\)\.html/.*|\1\2|'
```

Comment: That code seems to work. Unfortunately piping feedstail into sed twice breaks stuff. If I could rewrite my date changing stuff to work in the extended syntax, I'd probably get it into one sed command...

Comment: @fabsh added basic regexp, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The key to writing this sort of regular expression is to be *very* careful about what the boundaries of what you expect are, so as to avoid the random gunk that you want to get rid of causing you problems. Also, you should bear in mind that you can use characters other than `/` as part of a `s` operation's delimiters.

```
sed 's!\(http://www\.heise\.de/\)newsticker/meldung/[^./]*\(-[0-9]+\)\.html[^ ]*!\1\2!'
```

Be aware that getting the RE right can be quite tricky; assume you'll need to test it! (This is a key part of the “now you have two problems” quote; REs very easily become horrendous.)

Comment: You don't need to use `!` as a delimiter; any non-alphanumeric non-space character would do as well, provided it isn't already in use in the regular expression itself. I just like `!` as an alternate because I don't use it much elsewhere in my REs…

Comment: I *did* try it! `$ echo 'http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/WhatsApp-Ausfall-Server-Probleme-blockieren-Messaging-Dienst-2121664.html/from/atom10?wt_mc=rss.ho.beitrag.atom' | sed 's!\(http://www\.heise\.de/\)newsticker/meldung/[^./]*\(-[0-9]*\).html[^ ]*!\1\2!'` -->
`http://www.heise.de/-2121664`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
... | awk -F'[^0-9]*' '{print "http://www.heise.de/-"$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|\(//[^/]*/\).*\(-[0-9]\{7\}\).*|\1\2|' file
```

You can place the first sed command so:

```
feedstail -u http://www.heise.de/newsticker/heise-atom.xml -r -i 60 -f "{published}> {title} {link}" |
sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{13\}\)\(.\{6\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3\5/;s|\(//[^/]*/\).*\(-[0-9]\{7\}\).*|\1\2|'
```